# GitHub page returns 404 only for some files

Tags: git, github-pages

I've pushed to `gh-pages` my local `dist` folder containing the demo for my ng2 component with: `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

Everything's loading ok, **except** the `vendor...js/css` files.

my `gh-pages` website: https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/

my `gh-pages` source code: https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime/tree/gh-pages

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue today I only use github page to host a static site but it dislike my "vendor.bundle.js" which is generated by webpack(was working before though).

I searched all day and landed here soon as I change to "lib.bundle.js" it worked.

By the way .nojekyll file not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think there’s a default `vendor*` ignore pattern either in Jekyll or GitHub Pages. Does the problem go away if you touch a `.nojekyll` file in the repo?

Comment: thanks @zoul but it is not working for me - you can see the updated demo

Comment: The second obvious solution would be to change the file prefix, which, as I see, helped.

Comment: I had the same problem with a /vendor/bootstrap/ directory and the `.nojekyll` file did the trick.  https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages